# Database design for elements of different types but sharing some data

Tags: database-design

I am trying to learn what is the best way to approach turning a JSON (which is based on sealed serializable classes) into a good database structure. The current data I have is where there are different types of a specific element, each will have common and uncommon data. For example:

```
[
  {
    "type": "PERSON",
    "name": "John",
    "properties": {
      "a": "b",
      "c": "d"
    },
    "string": "Hello World"
  },
  {
    "type": "ANIMAL",
    "name": "Ani",
    "habitats": {
      "a": "b",
      "c": "d"
    },
    "string": "Hello World"
  },
  {
    "type": "PLANT",
    "name": "Bonsai",
    "needs": {
      "a": "b",
      "c": "d"
    },
    "string": "Hello World"
  }
]
```

Would it make more sense to have each type be a different table? I even considered just storing it as JSON but for example let's say I want to list all properties of a person, it would be really annoying to do so. Which probably wouldn't if it was a relational system.
What would be the best approach for this type of data?

Answer (score 0):

> Would it make more sense to have each type be a different table?

Yes, most likely that's a good place to start. When creating tables, I generally look for what are the objects at play, and base it off them.

I would assume on your application side, a `PERSON` is a separate object from an `ANIMAL`, and both being separate from the `PLANT` object. Similarly, should you create a separate table for each of them as well.